# Type Date Angular on Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I'm using Angular and ngx-bootstrap, but input type=date, don't work on Safari Browser. How can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Safari does not include a native datepicker for its desktop version.

As an around ways

You can give information about your date format using placeholder like this

```
<input type="date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" />
```

or you can force user to use correct format with regex pattern as below

```
<input type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" pattern="(^(((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[\/](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[\/](0[4,6,9]|11)))[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$)|(^29[\/]02[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)" >
```